# background video height is not working

Tags: html

This is my CSS:

```
video { 
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
    width: 980px;
    min-width: 980px;
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<video  playsinline autoplay muted loop>
    <source src="https://video.wixstatic.com/video/11062b_155feccf8d494b18b70adcd7716b6646/1080p/mp4/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

I am using this video in the background it's parent position is relative and width is 980px but height 100% is not working.

Comment: Are you want to Set Full Screen Background Video ? or Width 980px and width 100% ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `<video>` in a div and set `<video>`, `<div>`, `<body>`, and `<html>` to `width:100%` and `height:100%`. It should display a perfect video edge to edge without cropping or distortion at any size.

**SNIPPET**

```css
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  }
.frame {
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
}
video {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
<video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
  <source src="https://video.wixstatic.com/video/11062b_155feccf8d494b18b70adcd7716b6646/1080p/mp4/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" style="text-align:center">
    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="https://video.wixstatic.com/video/11062b_155feccf8d494b18b70adcd7716b6646/1080p/mp4/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>

video { 
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
    width: 980px;
    min-width: 980px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what's in the parent, the below works for me.

```
<style>
body, video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
  <video autoplay loop>
    <source src="https://video.wixstatic.com/video/11062b_155feccf8d494b18b70adcd7716b6646/1080p/mp4/file.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</body>
```